# date range - up to a range, but not over - in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a monthly recurring bill, and I want to send an email to the person 6 days before the expiration, and if its already been sent, not resend it. Working in PHP. I currently have two columns in the db: paidUntil and sentReminder, both DATETIME but I can change if necessary.

So, in psuedocode:

```
IF(between 6 days before expiration and expiration date AND reminder NOT sent)
  send reminder
  set that reminder was already sent
else
  if the month has past and time for new reminder, go back to top
```

Next month, restart the whole process. Note that people can expire on the 1st, 9th, or any given date of the month. Please help!

EDIT:  **I basically want to send a reminder, once, to somebody 6 or 5 days before their membership expires, every month**. That's all. here is some of my code, but I keep faltering on how to check if the time that i sent the last reminder has sufficiently passed to generate a new one... sorry for all the commenting here!!

```
        $paidUntil = strtotime($oneUser->paidUntil);
    $paidUntilMonthPrior = strtotime('-1 month', $paidUntil);

    $reminderSent = strtotime($oneUser->reminderSent);

    //$paidDateRemindRange = strtotime('-6 days', $paidUntil);      //6 days till u remind somebody
    $noNeedToSend = strtotime('+25 days', $reminderSent);

    //$paidDateReset = strtotime('+1 day', $paidUntil);

    //if($thisMonth==date('F',$paidUntil)) {
    //  $sameMonth=true;
    //}

    //if($todayTime>$paidDateReminder && $todayTime<$paidUntil && $todayTime>$reminderSent)
    //  $expirationRange=true;              

    if($todayTime < $noNeedToSend) {
        // is within 25 days from last sending - do nothing
    } 
    elseif($todayTime>$noNeedToSend && $todayTime<$paidUntil) {
        //is between 25 days and still less than the paid until time AND has not been sent this cycle
        // send expiration email and mark that its been sent
        $expirationRange=true;

    }
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Sounds doable to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We'll help fix broken code, but won't write this for you from scratch. Show that you've put some effort into it.

Comment: What both these guys said. Post some code, your explanation and pseudo code doesn't look like their talking about the same process to me.

Comment: that is not a code ????   how do you store the date , what format ???

Answer (score 0):

I think all good code starts with a solid plan. And you have a solid plan. It doesn't look like you need any help. And, generally, we only want to answer questions if people have already tried coding and get stuck.

But perhaps you're missing the logic for finding the difference between two `datetime`s? If so, here is an example:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-01-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-01-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
?>
```